# Android - Playing mp3 directly from the input stream without writing into temp files

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I'm creating an input stream to buffer and stream a mp3 from cloud .

```
URL url = new URL("http://xxxx.yyy.com/Demo.mp3");

InputStream inputStream = url.openStream();
```

Now how do i playback the mp3 from media player without using a temporary file to store it and read back from the same ? I'm developing for Android Lollipop

Comment: [Here is an answer for Android 6.0 onwards](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12920429/anyone-have-mediaplayer-working-with-parcelfiledescriptor-and-createpipe/52720388#52720388)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem persists even today !!! Check these link out https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=29870 and

http://www.piterwilson.com/blog/2014/03/11/android-mediaplayer-not-quite-there-yet/ . 
There is absolutely no way either to  get access and control over the MediaPlayer buffer , neither to feed the buffered mp3 content stored in an byte array into MediaPplayer as an argument to play it . So People either convert the mp3 buffer to PCM and use AudioTrack to play it or write the byte array of the input stream into a local socket and make Mediaplayer read back using the socket file descriptor like mentioned this following link [Audio stream buffering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4557450/audio-stream-buffering)

Comment: I haven't seen anyone get success with the 'inputstream -> socket file descriptor' method, the Android docs for MediaPlayer's setDataSource(fd) says: "The FileDescriptor must be seekable (N.B. a LocalSocket is not seekable). "
Please correct me if wrong as I'm using the local http server solution which is nasty.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure the MediaPlayer can handle remote URLs. Take a look at [this](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Android/Media/PlayMp3filefromaUrl.htm) example. Check the [`setDataSource`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#setDataSource(java.lang.String)) method from the `MediaPlayer` class as well.

EDIT: Since you really really want to use an inputstream, I think you'll need to go low-level. Check the [AudioTrack](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioTrack.html) class. This [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12263671/audiotrack-android-playing-sounds-from-raw-folder) might help. There are also a couple of issues [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/8SOXmAViLqU) and [here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=739#c7) that might be relevant.

Comment: I dont want to do that . MediaPlayer doesnt allow me to manage or get access to buffered content . I have a need to manipulate the buffered content , So i thought of doing the other way around , Stream the mp3  myself,buffer it  and then feed it to MediaPlayer . But i couldnt find a direct way to do it without writing this buffer into temporary files and reading back from them to play it using MediaPlayer ! This is what i want to achieve ..

Answer (score 0):

The solution I'm using to feed binary data directly to `MediaPlayer` is to use [ParcelFileDescriptor#createPipe()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/ParcelFileDescriptor.html#createPipe()) (API level 9) and [MediaPlayer#setDataSource(java.io.FileDescriptor)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#setDataSource(java.io.FileDescriptor)).

Here's sample code (untested):

```java
ParcelFileDescriptor[] pipe = ParcelFileDescriptor.createPipe();
FileDescriptor fd = pipe[0].getFileDescriptor();
mediaPlayer.setDataSource(fd);
OutputStream out = new ParcelFileDescriptor.AutoCloseOutputStream(pipe[1]);
```

From this point on, whatever you write in the output stream will be received by the `MediaPlayer`. This is pretty fast since it uses a kernel FIFO to transfer data (no sockets, no TCP) and as far as I understand is fully in RAM (no actual files are used).

Comment: I could't make it work, do you have a working example with this approach?