# Alternative to MediaPlayer

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

Actually i'm trying to play a sound inside my raw folder in the project,

The issue is that the device for which i'm developing the app doesn't support MediaPlayer and by following this [guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12263671/audiotrack-android-playing-sounds-from-raw-folder) in which the user use AudioTrack, the app just freeze every time the sound play.

So which should be the optimal alternative to MediaPlayer? The sounds i'm trying to play in my app are like "alert" sounds

Comment: try exoplayer bro it better to use that

Comment: [SoundPool](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/SoundPool) is suitable for short sound effects.

Comment: @MarkusKauppinen do you have any simple example on SoundPool use?

Comment: Nope. But I'm sure you'll find something here or via Google. It's probably commonly used in e.g. games.